# need advice about altering array formula

Tags: excel

I wrote an Excel program in which I am using the following array formula:

```
{=SMALL(IF($G$2=$B$2:$B$70,ROW($B$2:$B$70)-ROW($B$2)+1),ROW(1:2))}
```

Although the program works as desired, at some points the involved data is a non existing item which is displayed by the usual error notation #NUM!. I would prefer that, instead #NUM! the program displays a zero or, better still, a text such as "non existing". Please advise.

Comment: are you array entering this over two cells?

Comment: Yes. The data is contained in rows 2 to 70 in columns A & B